# Contact Roles on Opportunities - what kind of metadata is this?

Tags: metadata, opportunitycontactrole

I am researching Opportunity Contact Role and would like to understand its structure better.

In SF setup, you can find Opportunity Contact Role in the Object manager as an object with a set of out-of-the-box fields, one of those fields is a picklist field called Role, where you can select one of the default roles described by SF, or one that you have added as a customisation.

You can also type in Opportunity Contact Role into Quick search, then it comes up as “Contact Roles on Opportunities” – there it is described as “master list of picklist values for the Opportunity Contact Role field” – but what is it actually?

Is it a separate object? Is it a Global Value Set? Standard Value Set?
I can’t find any information about this “master list of picklist values for the Opportunity Contact Role field” in SF documentation, could you please advise?

Answer (score 1):

`OpportunityContactRole` is an object (a junction between `Opportunity` and `Contact`)

- It has a field called `Role` (see [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunitycontactrole.htm?q=opportunityContactRole)) that is a picklist
- The picklist values are represented in metadata as a [StandardValueSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm?q=standardvalueset) (basically, the OOTB picklists on standard objects)